# Modify $scope from within a service AngularJs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

I'm developing an application for geolocalization based on Gmaps Api. The thing is that for adding new markers by user events I've made a service that simple add a listener to the map events and add markers when its clicked. The issue is that I can't find a way to modify some $scope properties from within the service.
Here is the service that i've wrote:

```
climbingApp.factory('Markers', function(){
    return {
        addListener: function() {
            google.maps.event.addListener(
                map,
                'click',
                 function( e ) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: e.latLng,
                        map: map
                    });

                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

How can I return de e.latLng value and with that value set some $scope.property ?

Comment: you should avoid updating scope variable in service instead update in controller

Comment: and how could i pass the e.latKng value to the controller?

Comment: How are you calling addListener in your controller? Cant you just return e.LatLng?

Comment: I'dd injected the service into the controller and I just call the method addListener: myService.addListener()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Ajaybeniwal said, you shouldn't touch the scope outside a controller. You could change `addListener` so it accepts a callback:

```
climbingApp.factory('Markers', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        addListener: function(callback) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() { callback(e); });
            });
         }
    }
});
```

Now you can use it like this inside your controller:

```
Markers.addListener(function(e) {
    $scope.model.position = e.latLng;
});
```

You could also use a promise instead of a callback:

```
climbingApp.factory('Markers', function($rootScope, $q) {
    return {
        addListener: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() { deferred.resolve(e); });
            });
            return deferred.promise;
         }
    }
});
```

And then your controller would look like this:

```
Markers.addListener().then(function(e) {
    $scope.model.position = e.latLng;
});
```

Promises have an advantage over callbacks: you can bind them directly to a view and Angular will render the correct value as soon as it becomes available. Check out [this post](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) for more information on that matter.

Last but not least, please notice that you need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` in both cases so Angular triggers a digest cycle and everything gets processed correctly. That's required because Angular knows nothing about `google.maps.event.addListener` and it won't get notified when the gmaps callback is executed.

Comment: Thx!, I'll studie about promises !

Comment: This is a very good explanation, and amazing promisse example.