# Reusing functionality in angularjs controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tree renderer that displays interactive nodes. Here is a piece of such interaction:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 pull-left box-content" ng-click="loadEdit(node)">
    <div data-ng-if="!showEdit(node)" data-ng-include="formTemplates.display"></div>
    <div data-ng-if="showEdit(node)" data-ng-include="formTemplates.edit"></div>
</div>
```

The functions `showEdit(node)` and `loadEdit(node)` are defined from the controller. I now need to have several pages with different logic - I want different controllers that each have their own `showEdit(node)` and a few other specialized functions but I would like to reuse the `loadEdit(node)` function and many others because they are definitely common functionality.

Here is the aforementioned `loadEdit(node)`:

```
$scope.loadEdit = function(node) {
    if ($scope.selectedNode != undefined) {
        $scope.selectedNode.showEdit = false
    }
    node.showEdit = true;
    $scope.selectedNode = node;
}
```

The common answer to reusing functionality is to make a service so I was going to make pass `$scope` to a service but [a few people said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012501/modify-scope-from-within-a-service-angularjs) that you shouldn't modify `$scope` in a service (I would love if somebody elaborated on why I shouldn't do that). Besides, all these functions are incredibly shallow and adding a layer of indirection and writing a bunch of definitions like these `$scope.loadEdit = function(node) {return service.loadEdit(node, $scope.selectedNode);}` wouldn't even solve the problem - if I wanted to also modify an another variable, I would have to add it to every controller that uses this service function (and the fact that javascript does not care about the amount of arguments passed makes such a task very easy to forget)

Perhaps there is some way of packaging those common functions into an object and adding them to each controller like this? Though, I wouldn't know how to distribute this `object` to the controllers:

```
angular.extend({}, FooCtrl, commonFunctionsObject);
angular.extend({}, BarCtrl, commonFunctionsObject);
angular.extend({}, BazCtrl, commonFunctionsObject);
...
```

Can you do this with a javascript library, perhaps? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: what if split methods into different controllers? so you would have `loadController` with `.loadEdit()` and different controllers with their own `showEdit()`

Comment: The pattern you are describing is called [a mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) - you have some sort of container that holds properties and methods for *other* objects, so you combine them when you make an object. A *somewhat similar* but not entirely concept is [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). It's the point of the phrase "composition over inheritance". In short, you combine objects together to build up other objects. This makes the composite parts reusable and helps separate the functionality.

Comment: I've looked into mixins and it definitely seems like the exact functionality I want, thank you :)  
Seems weird that it needs setup just for something you would normally "include" in a procedural language.